# fetch the records based on the id

Tags: mysql

Here is my scenario

table name recipe which store `recipeid`, `recipetitle`

table name ingredient which store `ingredient`, `recipeid`, `amount`, `unit`

I want to fetch all the ingredients from the ingredient table based on particular recipeid with recipe details

Answer (score 0):

Use this way to fetch:

```
SELECT * FROM `ingredient` WHERE `recipeid` = 1
```

If you want them in a Comma Seperated Values, you can use:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`ingredient`)
    FROM `ingredient`
    WHERE `recipeid` = 1
    GROUP BY `recipeid`
```